# The element type 'Set<TableRow>' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow'

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a function that return a Table Row

```
TableRow buildRow(List<String> cells, {bool isHeader = false}) => TableRow(
      children: cells.map((cell) {
    final style = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: isHeader ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
      fontSize: 18,
    );

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        cell,
        style: style,
      )),
    );
  }).toList());
```

And I want to depict the Table if a certain condition is met:

```
Table(
                                border: TableBorder.all(),
                                children: [
                                  if (cartController.totalNum(produkt)! <
                                      11)
                                      { buildRow(
                                          ["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"],
                                          isHeader: true),}
```

But I get following error:

> The element type 'Set' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow'

Without the if statement my code works flawlessly, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```dart
Table(
  border: TableBorder.all(),
  children: [
    if (cartController.totalNum(produkt)! < 11)
      { buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true), } 
  ],
),
```

You are using a [collection if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators), which unlike a standard if statement, does not support using `{}` to denote the body of the `if`, instead it supports only a single expression as the body. Additionally, `{}` (containing comma separated values) is an expression that creates a [Set literal](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets) in dart. Essentially, you are creating a `List<Set<TableRow>>` when you want a `List<TableRow>`. All you need to do is remove the `{}` so you do not wrap each `TableRow` in a Set literal.

```dart
Table(
  border: TableBorder.all(),
  children: [
    if (cartController.totalNum(produkt)! < 11)
      buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true),
  ],
),
```

Comment: worked a charm, Thanks!

Comment: But is there nevertheless a way to add multiple statements?

Comment: @Nikita If you want to group multiple elements to a single collection for, it is possible by using the spread operator. If you read [this article](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c), there is an example and explanation towards the end where they do this: `if (!isAndroid) ...[Expanded(child: title), IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Never even heard of that

Answer (score 1):

Do it like

```dart
  if (cartController.totalNum(produkt)! < 11)
            buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true),
```

Others way to handle conditional if

```dart
body: Table(
  children: [
    if (1 < 2) buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true),
    if (1 < 2 && 3.isEven)
      buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true),
    //inline function
    () {
      if (1 == 3)
        return buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true);
      else if (1 > 3)
        return buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true);
      else
        return buildRow(["ab Menge", "Preis pro Stück"], isHeader: true);
    }()
  ],
```